# How can I write to a debug register in Windows?

Tags: windows, processor, msr

I want to write to a debug register on x64 Windows, from user mode.
What is the easiest way to do it?

(I could only come up with writing an assembly code inside a driver, and exporting this functionality)

Thanks!

Comment: You can't, only ring 0 code has access.  If you write a debugger then you use Get/SetContext() in your WaitForDebugEvent() handler so the values are in effect when you call ContinueDebugEvent()

Comment: You can do that even without writing a debugger (i.e. without having a debugger loop) - but the target thread has to be paused before using `SetContext`.

Comment: There used to be an ntdll api named NtSystemDebugControl (undocumented..). But I can't access it somehow.. Isn't there an alternative?